# Linux loses static IP on Ethernet on disonnection

Tags: networking, network-interface, systemd-networkd

I have a Linux (Ubuntu 20.04) which is running isc-dhcp-server on an ethernet interface. I configured a static IPv4 on the interface with the following lines in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto eno1
iface eno1 inet static
    address 129.111.169.50/16
    scope link
```

This works well on startup or after a `ifdown eno1 && ifup eno1`, however, when I unplug a Ethernet cable, it loses its static IP until I reboot or do the ifdown/ifup.

One strange thing: when I plug an ethernet cable, it gains an IPv6 (journalctl says `systemd-networkd: eno1: Gained IPv6LL`), which it keeps when I unplug the cable.

NetworkManager and isc-dhcp-server6 is disabled. Stopping isc-dhcp-server doesn't help. No dhclient is running.

Answer (score 1):

Found it!

First, I suspected sytemd-networkd to manage my interface. But there was no file in /etc/systemd/network. However, after learning how to use `networkctl status`, it revealed a .network file named `/run/systemd/network/10-netplan-eno1.network`.

Actually there was a leftover of subiquity, a file `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml`, which contained the configuration used during installation. Deleting this file did the trick.